# sql and php database entry 'lagging behind'

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a ratings system implemented but can't get it post the correct up to date rating in one of my database tables, it's always behind by one step, i.e. it always stores the last rating just before the current one:

The table 'post_rating' contains a row for every single vote cast on anything, and the table 'posts_rat_main' is where I'm having trouble. I want it to store an overall rating made up of all the individual votes on an item on the site, and keep queries to a minimum, but as said it's always one vote behind the current running total.

Main page

```
// set up the ratings 

$votes = mysql_query("SELECT rat_rating FROM post_rating WHERE rat_ID = $post_ID"); 
$votesnr = 0; 
$totalvotes = 0; 

while($vote = mysql_fetch_array($votes)){ 
$votesnr++; 
$totalvotes += $vote['rat_rating']; 
} 

if($votesnr == 0){ 
$rating = 0; 
} 
else { 
$rating = $totalvotes/$votesnr; 
} 

$roundedrating = floor($rating) + round($rating - floor($rating)) / 2 ; 

?> 
<div>Total Rating</div> 
<div class="star-rating" id="rating1result<?php echo $roundedrating; ?> "style="background-position:0 -<?php echo $roundedrating * 32; ?>px;"> 
<div class="star"></div> 
<div class="star"></div> 
<div class="star"></div> 
<div class="star"></div> 
<div class="star"></div> 
</div> 
<div class="result"> 
<span style="color:green"><?php echo round($rating,2); ?></span> (<?php echo $votesnr; ?> votes) 
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function(){ 

$('.star').mouseover(function (){ 
var star = $(this).index()+1; 
var x =(32 * star); 
$(this).parent().css('backgroundPosition... ' +(-x)+ 'px'); 
}); 

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){ 
var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1]; 
var y =(32 * originalresult); 
$(this).css('background-position','0%' +(-y)+ 'px'); 
}); 

}); 

$('.star').click(function (){ 
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('ratin... 
var vote = $(this).index() +1; 

$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url:"save_vote.php", 
data: 'id='+ id + '&vote='+ vote + '&stid=<?php echo $post_ID ?>' + '&totv=<?php echo $totalvotes ?>' + '&votes=<?php echo $votesnr ?>' 
}); 

$(this).parent().removeAttr("id"); 
$(this).parent().html(" "); 

window.location.href = "posts/post_view.php?id=<?php echo $post_ID ?>"; 
}); 

</script>`
```

This all works well with the 'post_rating' table, the handler scrip where I suspect the problem is reads:

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']); 
$vote = intval($_POST['vote']); 
$post_ID = intval($_POST['stid']); 
$votesnr = $_POST['votes']; 
$tot_v = $_POST['totv']; 

// set up the ratings 

$votesnr = $votesnr; 
$totalvotes = $tot_v; 

if($votesnr == 0){ 
$rating = 0; 
} 
else { 
$rating = $totalvotes/$votesnr; 
} 

$new_rat = round($rating,2); 

// Sling in the data 

$insert_rat = "INSERT INTO post_rating"; 
$insert_rat.= " (rat_ID,";  
$insert_rat.= " rat_rating,";
$insert_rat.= " rat_user_ID,";
$insert_rat.= " rat_user_name,";
$insert_rat.= " rat_date)";

$insert_rat.= " VALUES"; 
$insert_rat.= " ('$post_ID',";
$insert_rat.= " '$vote',"; 
$insert_rat.= " '$member_ID',"; 
$insert_rat.= " '$member_name',";
$insert_rat.= " NOW())";

$story_update = "UPDATE posts_rat_main"; 
$story_update.= " SET rating = '$new_rat'"; 
$story_update.= " WHERE st_ID = '$post_ID'"; 

mysql_query($insert_rat) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query($story_update) or die(mysql_error());
```

So whenever I update the table 'posts_rat_main' it updates it with the figure one vote behind the current vote!? I've got half of this from a tutorial and messed about it with to no avail. I'm lousy with javascript and just can't figure it out but suspect the problem lays in my 'save_vote' handler script which seems very simple.

My latest attempt was to nick the script commented '// set up the ratings', from the 'main page' and paste it into the save_vote handler script as shown here, but to no avail. I'm fairly stumped, any ideas?

Also as a secondary note I've found this script to be a little unresponsive at times, requiring sometimes 2 or 3 clicks on the stars before it will register the vote, and I can't imagine why that is?

Any help much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is that you have to add **$vote** to **$totalvotes** and **+1** to **votesnr**:

```
$rating = ($totalvotes + $vote) / ($votesnr + 1);
```

This will also allow you to remove the if/else, since the denominator will at least be 1.

**The longer answer**

If there is an index for **rat_id, rat_rating** on **post_rating**, then it is probably a better idea to just do a group by sql select query when you want the results.  Unless you really have a problem, a preo-ptimization such as this is not worth the time or trouble.

If you *must* have a separate table to store the results, then at least use a trigger on **post_rating** to compute the result instead of doing in it in php.

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, thanks. The lag and clicking it a few times to make it works still happens but the maths are good. I ditched the if/else and replaced it with your one line.
My sql is not so hot tho and I'm not sure what you mean by your 'group by' or 'trigger' ideas

Comment: @MrC, please mark as accepted since it worked.  It's a lot to explain how triggers and aggregate functions work.  You best just research it.